# Pasar un variable a tipo date

Tags: javascript

Como puedo pasar a un tipo `Date` la variable que se muestra a continuación:

```
var valor1 = document.getElementById("fecha_inicio").value;
```

Es enviada desde un `input` y el valor que llega es de esta manera `"YYYY-mm-dd"`.

Comment: Ese es un formato "estandar" por lo que puedes hacer : `var fecha = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha_inicio").value);` Puedes ver mas información aquí: [Date Formats](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Crea un nuevo objeto 'Date' con el valor recibido, ese formato es aceptado sin necesidad de desglosarlo o modificarlo.

Mira el ejemplo.

```js
var selectedDate = document.getElementById("inputDate").value;
var textDate = document.getElementById("textDate"); 
var dayValue = document.getElementById("day"); 
var monthValue = document.getElementById("month"); 
var yearValue = document.getElementById("fullYear");

// De esta forma crear el objecto Date    
var formattedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
      
var day = formattedDate.getDate();
var month = formattedDate.getMonth()+1;
var year = formattedDate.getFullYear();

      
textDate.innerHTML = formattedDate;
dayValue.innerHTML = day;
monthValue.innerHTML = month;
yearValue.innerHTML = year;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Date</h2>

<p>Fecha: <input id="inputDate" value="2019-07-30"></input></p>

<p>Fecha indicada:  <b><span id="textDate"></span></b></p>
<p>Día:             <b><span id="day"></span></b></p>
<p>Mes:             <b><span id="month"></span></b></p>
<p>Año completo:    <b><span id="fullYear"></span></b></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos verifica como muestra "Mes:6" cuando debería ser "Mes:7"

Comment: Cierto es, olvidé que los valores devueltos van de 0 a 11 en lugar de 1 a 12. Gracias por la puntualización.